# How to make a function that concatenetes strings in python

Tags: python

I'm taking the codeacademy course and it asks me the following:

> Define a function called join_strings accepts an argument called
>   words. It will be a list. Inside the function, create a variable
>   called result and set it to "", an empty string. Iterate through the
>   words list and append each word to result. Finally, return the result.
>   Don't add spaces between the joined strings!

So what I did is:

```
def join_strings(words):
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(words)):
        result = words
    return result
```

But the console prints me:

```
Oops, try again. join_strings(['x', 'y', 'z', 'a']) returned ['x', 'y', 'z', 'a'] instead of 'xyza'
```

Comment: No, you didn't do that, that code would not return anything but crash on the `return`.

Comment: Misspelling corrected

Answer (score 2):

```
def join_strings(words):
    result = ""
    for i in words:
        result += i
    return result
```

you have missed this `result += words` concatenation part  and return `result`

you have to use this

```
for i in words:
            result += i
```

Update

```
def join_strings(words):
    result = ""
    for i in words:
        result += i
    return result

g= join_strings(['x', 'y', 'z', 'a'])

print(g)

o/p : xyza
```

**From your post :**

```
def join_strings(words):
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(words)):
        result += words[i]
    return result

g= join_strings(['x', 'y', 'z', 'a'])

print(g)
```

You have to use the index value of the word. Since you are getting the range and iterating you have to specify the index  `result += words[i]`

Comment: Those who downvoted please tell me the reason. I am getting the proper o/p. why did you downvoted then ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
def join_strings (words):
    result = ""
    for i in words:
        result += i
    return result
```

Basically, we have an empty string. We can add more to this string by using the `+=` operator. This operator is short for saying `x = x + y`.

Comment: Get rid of the unnecessary semi-colons.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
from operator import add
def join_strings(words):
    return reduce(add, words)
```

Comment: This does not satisfy the assignment, which is, essentially, to write the join function

Comment: Code only answers  are [generally discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques) unless they answer the question in full and are "self documenting" (contentious term).  This answer doesn't follow the method outlined in the brief and isn't self documenting, so I don't think it fulfils those criteria.

Answer (score -1):

The following has worked for me:

```
n = ["Michael", "Lieberman"]
```

## Add your function here

```
def join_strings(words):
    result = ""
    for i in range(len(words)):
        result += words[i]
    return result

print join_strings(n)
```

Comment: Please avoid posting an answer wich is identical to another previously posted.